# Can none and nor be used together?

Tags: grammar, neither-nor

Are the following sentences gramatically correct:

"None of Tom, Dick nor Harry participated in the contest."
"None of Tom, nor Dick, nor Harry participated in the contest."

If it were a two-person list, the neither-nor construction would clearly be correct ("Neither Tom nor Harry participated"). It seems to me that nor remains the correct conjunction in a three-person list, but I can't find any supporting references.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Neither of those sentences are correct. In fact, I might say:

> Neither the first sentence, nor the second one, nor any hypothetical third one, is correct

You use *none* with a plural noun, which obviates the need for a *nor* anywhere:

> None of the boys participated in the contest

Comment: Or maybe "None of the three, neither Tom nor Dick nor Harry, participated."

Comment: Sure, that works.

Comment: I should say that *neither-nor* does not sound right to me if used with more than two options.  Like *both*, they come from the Old English dual number and are not fully plural yet in all dialects.

Comment: @Anonym Sounds perfectly fine to me. Notice that the OED supports as one sense for *neither* the following: **“Not any one (of more than two)”**. It’s been used that way for centuries now — and still is.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, so it has been said here (and so it apparently says in the OED). Still sounds very wrong to me. To me, *either* and *neither* only sound correct with a single *or*.